# Android application has stopped when adding onCompletionListener to mPlayer

Tags: android, android-activity, media-player

I am having a problem:

What I am trying to do is to finish an activity once the audio has been played. I use the the following code:

```
public void addButtonListener() {

    mPlay = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.bPlay);

    mPlay.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override

        public void onClick(View view) {

            Toast.makeText(Punto.this, "ImageButton is working!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
           /* mPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(Punto.this,
                    Uri.parse(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath() + "/omw/zipSample/1.ogg"));
            mPlayer.start();*/
            String A = final_route + uriAudio;
            mPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(Punto.this, Uri.parse(final_route + uriAudio));
            mPlayer.start();
            mPlayer.setOnCompletionListener(new MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener() {

                @Override
                public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {
                    mp.release();
                    finish();
                }

            });

        }

    });

}
```

If I just remove the 'setOnCompletionListener', then it works (without having finished the activity). What am I doing wrong?

Thanks.

Comment: add setOnCompletionListener before mplayer.start().

Comment: why not paste the crash exception stack.

Answer (score 0):

use this following line instead of your line " mp.release(); "

public void addButtonListener() {

```
mPlay = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.bPlay);

mPlay.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

    @Override

    public void onClick(View view) {

        Toast.makeText(Punto.this, "ImageButton is working!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
       /* mPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(Punto.this,
                Uri.parse(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath() + "/omw/zipSample/1.ogg"));
        mPlayer.start();*/
        String A = final_route + uriAudio;
        mPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(Punto.this, Uri.parse(final_route + uriAudio));

        mPlayer.setOnCompletionListener(new MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener() {

            @Override
            public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {
                if(mPlayer!=null){
                mPlayer.release();
                  mPlayer=null;
                finish();
                 }
            }

        });
```

mPlayer.start();
        } //

```
});
```

}